# Google Sheets : How to find and calculate the value in data table where date is between two dates

Tags: javascript, date, google-sheets, vlookup, currency

I'm trying to make my account expense where I order the product from oversea that has different exchange rate.

I have two separate spread sheets
1.Currency EXC which I use to add my exchange rate and amount data.

```
Date        Amount      EXC Rate
07/01/2021  ₩ 200,000   0.0276
12/01/2021  ₩ 400,000   0.0275
15/01/2021  ₩ 103,600   0.0274
16/01/2021  ₩ 200,000   0.0274
22/01/2021  ₩ 100,000   0.0273
```

2.Purchase Order Which I use to record the item I bought.

```
Date        Product Item     Price     QTY
03/01/2021  item1            ₩ 14,900   10
12/01/2021  item2            ₩ 14,900   5
15/01/2021  item3            ₩ 33,000   3
```

I want to know the price I bought in my local currency according to the date I did money exchange.
For example : I bought item 1 on January 3rd which I exchange the money at 0.0276 per ₩ 200,000. That means I bought item 1 at 411.24 x 10 = 4112.40.
The total money in my pocket = 200,000 - 149,000 = 51,000 then I bought another item on January 12th but I still have the money left 51,000. The total expense for item2 were 74,500 that mean 51,000 x 0.0276 = 1407.60 and 23,500 x 0.0275 = 646.25

I want to auto calculate these data in another google spread sheets but I don't know how to make formula for this.

Thank you.

Comment: I see that first purchase order was done earlier than first exchange of currency. Is it OK? Or I am missing something?

Comment: Oh sorry, because these are just sample data.

Comment: What did you try till now? Do you have a formula you're working on? Can you provide a copy of the spreadsheet you're working on (free of sensitive information)?